# How to align the text in verify email body - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, email, text, alignment

I am trying to align the text in verify email body to be on the right rather than left

the verification email will be in Arabic so I need it to be from right to left not the other way around

is there any file I need to edit or I need to do it inside the "VerifyEmail" class? and how?

Comment: can you show how it looks now.how it should you would like to do changes

Comment: Please share a code or image of your Email Body. But still, you can use `direction: rtl` property in your css `VerifyEmail` css class or put `dir=rtl` in the `html` tag.